# extract index of a grid view inside if another grid view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I want to extract the correct index of a grid view inside another grid view. like the picture below:
I want to extract the index of Checked grid view. I mean when user click on cancel assigning button the right index will extract for each rows in all records in grid view.
[image]

For single grid view i use this cod:

```
int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        idx = idx - (GridView1.PageSize * GridView1.PageIndex);
```

But when i use a grid view inside another one, i don't know what to do!!
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `RowCommand`-handler for the inner grid, you can cast the `sender` argument to type `GridView` to get a reference to the inner grid.

```
<asp:GridView ... OnRowCommand="InnerGridView_RowCommand">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

```cs
protected void InnerGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridView innerGridView = (GridView) sender;

    if (e.CommandName == "CancelAssigning")
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        index -= innerGridView.PageSize * innerGridView.PageIndex;

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want the index of the outer grid, the easiest solution would be to include that in the command-argument.